# get the current values from the detailview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am developing a quiz engine in asp.net and Sql as db. I fetched all the  questions  of quiz from database using a sqldatsource  and then databind that sql datasource to a detailview

And when the user press the Submit button after selecting an answer the system will save the current questionnumber and the user's answer to a array-list  and the detailview pageindex will be incremented to show the next question

But the issue is I am not able to get the current row of data bound to the dataview  how can i get the current question number from the Detailview. Can anyone help?

### ASP.NET:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
                 BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                 CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="Vertical" 
                 Height="50px" Width="477px" ForeColor="Black">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" HeaderText="Question" 
                        SortExpression="Question" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer 1" HeaderText="Answer 1" 
                        SortExpression="Answer 1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer 2" HeaderText="Answer 2" 
                        SortExpression="Answer 2" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer 3" HeaderText="Answer 3" 
                        SortExpression="Answer 3" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer 4" HeaderText="Answer 4" 
                        SortExpression="Answer 4" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Correct Answer" HeaderText="Correct Answer" 
                        SortExpression="Correct Answer" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" SortExpression="Id" />
    </Fields>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:DetailsView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizEngineConnectionString %>" 
                   SelectCommand="SELECT Question_Bank.Qstn_id AS Id, Qusetion_Master.Question, Qusetion_Master.Answer1 AS [Answer 1], Qusetion_Master.Answer2 AS [Answer 2], Qusetion_Master.Answer3 AS [Answer 3], Qusetion_Master.Answer4 AS [Answer 4], Qusetion_Master.CorrectAns AS [Correct Answer] FROM Qusetion_Master INNER JOIN Question_Bank ON Qusetion_Master.QuestionID = Question_Bank.Qstn_id WHERE (Question_Bank.Quiz_id = @Param1)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="Param1" 
                                  QueryStringField="quizid" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="23px" Width="128px">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Answer1">Answer 1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Answer 2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Answer3">Answer 3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Answer 4</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click"
                Text="Next" Width="121px" />
```

### Code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {   
        //Save off previous answers
        System.Data.DataRowView dr = (System.Data.DataRowView)DetailsView1 .DataItem;
        // Create Answer object to save values
        Answer a = new Answer();
        a.QuestionID = dr[0].ToString();
        a.CorrectAnswer = dr["Correct Answer"].ToString();
        a.UserAnswer = DropDownList1 .SelectedValue.ToString();

        ArrayList al = (ArrayList)Session["AnswerList"];
        al.Add(a);

        //  Session.Add("AnswerList", al);
        //  DetailsView1.PageIndex++;
    } Catch(exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try use DetailsView1.Rows[5].Cells[1].Text get your  Correct Answer

Comment: @KingJk  means for every oage index increment (every question I will get correct answer by using the DetailsView1.Rows[5].Cells[1].Text"?

Comment: it mean if your correct answer is fix rows number,you can use DetailsView1.Rows[5] (it's last 2 Row), or it's dynamic ?

Comment: @KingJk it worked If you could add it as answer I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it mean if your correct answer is fix rows number,you can use DetailsView1.Rows[5] (it's last 2 Row), or it's dynamic ?

Comment: `code`a.QuestionID = DetailsView1.Rows[6].Cells[1].Text;
            a.Question = DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;   
            a.CorrectAnswer = DetailsView1.Rows[5].Cells[1].Text; `code`

Comment: it gives me what I want